# MDN bind why concat arguments when calling apply

Tags: javascript, bind, apply

MDN specifies a polyfill bind method for those browsers without a native bind method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

This code has the following line:

```
aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
```

Which is passed as the args to the apply method on the function:

```
fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                             ? this
                             : oThis,
                           aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
```

However, this line actually repeats the arguments, so that if I called the bind method as:

```
fnX.bind({value: 666}, 1, 2, 3)
```

the arguments passed to fnX are:

```
[1, 2, 3, Object, 1, 2, 3]
```

Run the following example and see the console output http://jsfiddle.net/dtbkq/

However the args reported by fnX are [1, 2, 3] which is correct. Can someone please explain why the args are duplicated when passed to the apply call but don't appear in the function arguments variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arguments` are in two different contexts there. Each time a function is invoked, among other things, an `arguments` object is set to all the arguments passed (if the `arguments` is accessed).

The first mention of `arguments` are the arguments to `bind()`, which will become initial arguments.

The second mention are the next set of arguments called on the bound proxy function. Because the `arguments` name would shadow its parent `arguments` (as well as the `this` context needing to be separated), they are stored under the name `aArgs`.

This allows for partial function application (sometimes referred to as *currying*).

```
var numberBases = parseInt.bind(null, "110");

console.log(numberBases(10));
console.log(numberBases(8));
console.log(numberBases(2));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9RkH/).

Comment: @Matt You must have a funny definition of time then ;)

Comment: true, didn't realise the display order was not time based, there you go

Answer (score 1):

No. As you log from `x`, *`x() arguments:`* are *`[1, 2, 3]`*.

From `bind2` you `console.log(aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));`, where `aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)`. So what else than *`[1, 2, 3, {value: 666}, 1, 2, 3]`* do you expect? Those are not the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) passed to fnX, but those passed to bind: `[{value: 666}, 1, 2, 3]`.

Inside the bound function, the `aArgs` variable still contains `[1, 2, 3]`, while the `arguments` now are empty - you did call `x()`.

Comment: see above, the console.log call was out of scope

Comment: Yes, just what I said - you logged the arguments of `bind` plus the `aArgs`, which are the sliced arguments of `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

If you instead check the value of `aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))` from within `fBound` you'll see what you would expect. The key is that arguments refers to the additional arguments called on an already bound function.

Comment: Thanks figured it out - you can obviously pass arguments to x() like x(4) which is the extra args that are concat'd to the bound args.