# Modifying the bind native function of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, bind

I went through a code snippet today as below:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

What I actually got is that I'm building a samsung smart TV application and I found this code in one of the sample app codes. May be the smart tv JavaScript engine doesn't have any bind prototype on the `Function` object and doesn't support to bind the event. That's why the author tried to create a new bind prototype on the native `Function` object.

But I'm really not getting rest of the code and what it is really doing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MDN bind why concat arguments when calling apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003475/mdn-bind-why-concat-arguments-when-calling-apply)

Comment: This is [MDN's Function.prototype.bind polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill). There are several existing questions on StackOverflow about various aspects of the implementation.